# r - choosing correct nnet model

Tags: r, caret, nnet

**Language: R**

**Background**

data = 1800 observations (rows) x 5 variables (columns)

I am using `library(caret)` and training regression models using `nnet()` and would like to know whether my interpretation and choice of model is valid.

My response variable is in hours (therefore continuous and non-negative)

**Method**

In this example I am training three models, the only difference between them is the number of max iterations (`maxit`) (to try and 'smooth' the values at the high-end of the range).

I have also split my data into a training `df_train` and a test `df_test` dataset using `createDataPartition()`.

```
# use 10-fold cross-validation
cvCtrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", repeats=3)
modFit_1 <- train(v_response ~., method="nnet", trControl=cvCtrl, data=df_train, trace=TRUE, maxit=1000, linout = 1)
modFit_2 <- train(v_response ~., method="nnet", trControl=cvCtrl, data=df_train, trace=TRUE, maxit=2000, linout = 1)
modFit_3 <- train(v_response ~., method="nnet", trControl=cvCtrl, data=df_train, trace=TRUE, maxit=4000, linout = 1)
```

The plots of predicted vs actual values are for each model, and their `RMSE` values are:

[image: modFit_1]

```
RMSE = 17.31634
```

[image: modFit_2]

```
RMSE = 16.73134
```

[image: modFit_3]

```
RMSE = 9.526294
```

**Questions**

1. As my response variable has to be non-negative would I immediately assume `modFit_2` to be the 'best' model out of the three (even though `modFit_3` has a lower RMSE)?
2. Is there a way to ensure the predicted values are non-negative (and is my `modFit_2` non-negative just by chance)?

**Update**

Distribution of `v_response`

[image: v_response_distribution]

Residual vs fitted plot

```
df_diag <- data.frame(residuals = modFit_3$finalModel$residuals, 
                        fitted = modFit_3$finalModel$fitted.values)

ggplot(data=df_diag, aes(x=fitted, y=residuals)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: residual_v_fitted]

Comment: Very interesting plots: how did you produce the ones which show predicted vs actual values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plots of modFit_3 looks perfect to me:
a straight 45° degree line and the  errors look homoscedastic.
Please, check the homoscedasticity by plotting errors vs predicted values.
If it is so, can't you just use `max(0, predicted)` for a (very) few negative values?

A general way to ensure non-negativity of the response is log-transform it before training, that is

```
train(log(v_response) ~., method="nnet", ...)
```

and then inverse transform the predicted values.
But this may also have other effects, in particular change error distribution. 
So be careful.
For deciding about log-transform it would also be helpful to see the histogram of v_response

In your code you are using `linout = 1`, which is linear activation function. This is very similar (though not equivalent) to linear regression. It allows negative values. You can try other activation functions, such as [rectifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_%28neural_networks%29), but this is out of the "nnet" scope. I suspect that the default value of linout (logistic) that introduces nonlinearities in the model (actually, the main purpose of neural network) did not give you satisfactory results. But if your problem is linear by nature (seems so based on your perfect modFit_3 plot), why do you bother with nnet and don't try linear regression?

Comment: I've updated my question with a plot of fitted v residuals, and also the distribution of `v_response`. (I initially tried linear regression but wasn't getting good results, so I started exploring other techniques such as trees and neural nets)

Comment: And for `linout = FALSE` I do indeed get incorrect results (just 1s) - [as per this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21641448/4002530)

Comment: @tosplg Your `v_response` distribution has a long tail and residuals are larger for large fitted values (which means, some heteroscedasticity is there). Therefore, yes,  log-transforming `v_response` looks reasonable in your case.

Comment: I thought you might say that and tried it with a `log(v_resposne)`, but it gave me a worse fitting model with very distinct patterns in the residual vs fitted plot.

Comment: @tosplg Yes, one cannot say in advance what is better. Anyway with linear activation function it is only by chance that you do not have negative values as in modFit_2